# Rust: How can one access state from the surrounding scope when implementing a trait without explicitly passing it as parameter?

Tags: rust, parameter-passing, traits

A bit of context first, as motivation why I am asking the question: Im currently implementing a custom deserializer using [serde](https://serde.rs/) for a struct owning trait-objects. The concrete type of the trait-objects is unknown at compile time, as those can be loaded from an external library at runtime. That makes it impossible to statically choose concrete types for deserialization. Instead I need to look up the concrete types at runtime, using a helper struct (`PluginManager`) that I somehow need to get into the custom deserializer's scope. Currently I'm using global thread-local storage for this, and that is working fine, but it's imho a pretty ugly solution...

So, the actual question is:
When implementing a function for a trait from another crate (meaning: with no way to modify function signatures), for internal usage of that other crate (meaning: no direct control over function parameters that get passed in), and no `self` parameter, how can one get state from the surrounding scope into the implemented function?

Let's take a part of my `Deserialize` implementation as example. This gets called from within a derived (meaning: auto-generated) deserialize function of the containing struct (`ProgramConfig`). The `Deserialize` trait is from the serde crate, the `Deserializer` is from another crate as well, only `PluginConfig` is my own type.

```
let plugin_manager : PluginManager;
.......
struct PluginConfigVisitor;
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for PluginConfig {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<PluginConfig, D::Error>
    where D: Deserializer<'de> {
        const FIELDS: &'static [&'static str] = &["plugin", "config"];
        deserializer.deserialize_struct("PluginConfig", FIELDS, PluginConfigVisitor)
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do however would be something along the lines of

```
let plugin_manager : PluginManager;
.......
struct PluginConfigVisitor(&PluginManager);
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for PluginConfig {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<PluginConfig, D::Error>
    where D: Deserializer<'de> {
        const FIELDS: &'static [&'static str] = &["plugin", "config"];
        deserializer.deserialize_struct("PluginConfig", FIELDS, PluginConfigVisitor(plugin_manager))
    }
}
```

where the `plugin_manager` is in the enclosing scope of the whole deserialization.

So, how do I get the reference to the `plugin_manager` into that function?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the [`DeserializeSeed`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.125/serde/de/trait.DeserializeSeed.html) trait from serde.

Comment: I'm already using `DeserializeSeed` in the `PluginConfigVisitor::visit_map()`. My problem is that I somehow need to pass the object with the state there first.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't really precise: DeserializeSeed is of course an option, but that would require passing the seed through all outer structs, meaning those would need hand-written deserializers as well, instead of just deriving the Serialize trait.

Comment: After giving it some thought, I think I'll go with your suggestion, @jonasbb. I'll refactor a few structs, so that in the end only 2 levels of hand-written DeserializeSeed implementations are required, to keep the maintenance load acceptable. However the original question still stands (with "does not work" being a fully acceptable answer).

Comment: As for "how do I get X into a function", the answer is that rust functions cannot access the scope in which they're defined. X must be either a global or an argument of the function.

Comment: @Kvothe, please make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it then.